# How to automatically make the browser open localhost after ng serve in angular?

Tags: angular, linux

Is there any way to make my terminal to open localhost after ng serve command is completed in angular 8.

Comment: check this:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

Comment: you can mark the answer as accepted that has worked for you thanks

Answer (score 22):

Use the following command:

```
ng serve -o
```

or

```
ng serve --open
```

If you would like to add some option when you want to run your Angular projects such as opening a browser or running your project on a specific port like 4600 or another option
you will have a long command

Add the following command in the package.json under the scripts section:

```
"start": "ng serve --open --port 4600"
```

Finally to run

```
npm run start
```

### UPDATED

Angular's CLI internally uses [opn npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn) when you pass that `-o` or `--open` flag

Currently, the CLI doesn't support passing more options to the opn package, therefore it will open the site using your system's default browser.

Comment: And how can I open it on the same tab?

Comment: @AndyNope- Updated

Answer (score 6):

set it up in angular.json

```json
{
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "ng-router:build",
      "open": true,
      "port": 4200
    },
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "browserTarget": "ng-router:build:production"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

"open": true, this works well

Comment: This is the best answer, thank you very much. This is the first thing I'm doing when I'm setting a new angular app.

Comment: Is there any way to target a specific browser when using this configuration? For example, I keep Chrome as my default system browser, but I open Firefox while in development.

Comment: @carloswm85 yes we can. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/5689  this can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. edit **package.json** and
2. add -o switch here "start": **"ng serve -o"** it is in scripts.

[image]

Note: you have to run it using npm like **npm run start**

Comment: Is it possible to select what browser I'll use? Other than the system default.

Answer (score 0):

While serving the app just add an extra flag `ng serve -o`
It'll do the job.

Comment: or "ng s -o" for simplicity