# Angular: Launch and Debug in regular Chrome

Tags: angular

When I open my regular Google Chrome browser, I have a browser with bookmarks and a theme applied to it. But when I launch and debug my Angular application, it starts a special version of chrome, without any search history too for example.

Now this is a problem. For my angular app I am integrating Firebase authentication with Google and the latter simply refuses logging in because of the browser as you can see on the screenshot below.

[image]

When however I open my regular Google Chrome and browse to `http://localhost:4200/` to use my login button, all works fine.

So how do I configure Angular to open the regular Chrome browser instead of the one it is using now?

These are my configurations

**launch.json**

```
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Run & debug",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/*"
      },
    },
    {
      "name": "ng test",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: test",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start",
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": {
            "regexp": "(.*?)"
          },
          "endsPattern": {
            "regexp": "bundle generation complete"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "test",
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": {
            "regexp": "(.*?)"
          },
          "endsPattern": {
            "regexp": "bundle generation complete"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's all just default except for the `sourceMaps` and `sourceMapPathOverrides` because otherwise it would not hit breakpoints in VS Code.

Comment: Google knows that Chrome has been launched in a sort of dev-mode (with debugger attached and debug port set) so it won't allow that session to login.  (security thing...)   So try running from VS Code without debugger.  Angular is not launching the browser, the IDE is.

Comment: You are correct that it is indeed VsCode that launches Chrome, but is there a way to make it open a regular, non-dev instance of it AND still be able to debug it?

Comment: I think Angular can launch the browser from CLI... "ng serve -o"? That should launch default browser... See answers here: 
 "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041042/how-to-automatically-make-the-browser-open-localhost-after-ng-serve-in-angular

Comment: Not sure if there's a way for the IDE to debug without the flag set on startup.  It's possible there's some kind of browser extension that could tie the two, but beware of security implications.

Comment: For me, I only use debugger on the back-end... and use alerts or console for debugging front-end.  (just got used to that way back when...)

Comment: You can also set breakpoints in Chrome's dev tools:  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/  (though that may not be all that useful with compiled Angular code... never tried it myself)